# Single type for entry submission on error loses entry object

Tags: saveentry, plugin-guestentries

I have created a contact form inside a single entry type 'contact' for front end submissions.
This lets me display editing options for title and body and display the form.

When submitting the form, the entry object ( eg entry.title ) disappears and no title or body  content is shown - just the form with its corresponding errors.

So submitting it seems to lose the entry - is this because it is returning the saved entry model and not the single that it is on?

Comment: Can you add the template code you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the README](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/blob/master/README.md):

> If there is a validation error on the entry, then the page will be reloaded with an `entry` variable available to it...

You can override the variable name by setting the `entryVariable` config setting, as follows:

```
<?php

// File: craft/config/guestentries.php

return [
    'entryVariable' => 'guestEntry',
];
```

Once you've done that, the page entry model will be available as `entry`, and the "guest entries" entry model (containing any validation errors) will be available as `guestEntry`.